# Brewing a NEIPA under pressure: magnet in dry hop bag is stuck to the tilt hydrometer. Should I open & remove?

Tags: dry-hop, pressure

I'm brewing a NEIPA in a Kegland Fermzilla under 10psi of pressure, and I planned to have 2 dry hops without depressurizing or opening the fermentor. I have a tilt hydrometer in the fermentor and things have been going well so far - dropped from 1.06 to 1.026 in 4 days.

The first dry hops I prepared in a bag containing a magnet so that I can pull away the magnet from the outside and drop the bag into the beer. You can see this technique here: https://youtu.be/lvPBEwoTDPM?t=485

The problem is, I didn't weight the bag enough and when the bag dropped it pretty much floated on the top. Now the other thing that's floating on the top is my tilt hydrometer. Today I noticed that the hydrometer reading spiked back up to 1.048 and that the tilt is sitting alongside the hop back, so it's clearly stuck to the magnet. I'm worried the tilt ($160!) will get damaged by the magnet. It's still transmitting for now.

So the dilemma is... should I depressurize the fermentor, reach in, and separate the tilt from the hop bag?

This would give me peace of mind about the tilt and allow me to get a more accurate sense of when fermentation is done, but it would also risk oxidizing the beer... Given that fermentation is still active, maybe if I do it gently and quickly re-seal and re-pressurize it'll be ok?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly difficult for anything other than a strong magnet to mess up electronics - however a Tilt does not have magnetic storage as far as I am aware.

If it's attached to the side of the battery - I wouldn't worry about it.